# difference in mysql workbench foreign key styling

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagram

I got two MySQL Workbench Model files (.mwb) with an EER Diagram from two colleagues. They both have foreign keys. One file connect the line, to visualize the foreign key, somewhere to the table while the other points directly at the keys row:

[image: foreign key table connection]

1) foreign key table connection

[image: foreign key direct row connection]

2) foreign key direct row connection

Is this just a styling option of the MySQL Workbench, or are there "real world" difference. I´m only able to create the first type. How can i make same look like the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship style used in the models can be selected from a number of different styles MySQL Workbench supports:

[image]

and are purly visual variants, without any sideeffect on the generated foreign key.

Crow's Foot is the default (shown in the first image) and Connect to Columns is used in the second.

I also recommend that you play with the properties of the relationship. Double click on the line to open the editor, which gives you a number of options and allows to change the type of the relationship (mandatory, identifying, 1:n, 1:1 etc.).